# apt-get update; install apache2: works on 1 VM, fails on another, with the same mirror config: [Not candidate version]

Tags: apt, pinning

### Setup

I have 3 VMs, each running 12.04:

VM0: hosts a debmirror-built, partial ubuntu repository.
VM1 & VM2 want to use that to install packages.

I've renamed `/etc/apt/sources.list -> /etc/apt/sources.list.dis` so that it's not picked up (and I don't see the VMs hitting the standard ubuntu archives during apt-get update), and both VMs have identical identical sources.list configs (1 file in `sources.list.d/foo.list`)

### The problem

On one VM, I can install `apache2` from my ubuntu mirror just fine, but not on the other. Is there any stale apt-get state that I need get rid of?

`foo.list`:

```
deb http://my-mirror.com/repository/ubuntu/ precise main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://my-mirror.com/repository/ubuntu/ precise-security main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://my-mirror.com/repository/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe multiverse restricted
```

Before trying to install apache2 on both VMs, I ran: `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/apt` and `sudo apt-get update`

VM1 works fine:

```
me@vm1-172-16-2-18:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap
  ssl-cert
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec apache2-suexec-custom openssl-blacklist
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-worker apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
  libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 48 not upgraded.
Need to get 102 kB/1,857 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,686 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
...
```

VM2 doesn't:

```
me@vm2-172-16-2-17:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2 is a virtual package provided by:
  apache2-mpm-itk 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-worker 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-event 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-itk 2.2.22-1ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-worker 2.2.22-1ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-prefork 2.2.22-1ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]
  apache2-mpm-event 2.2.22-1ubuntu1 [Not candidate version]

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
me@vm2-172-16-2-17:~$
```

`apt-get update` didn't report any errors.

**How can I troubleshoot this issue?**

Things I've established so far:

- Clearly the repository is working, since 1 VM can install from it, so I think it must be something to do with apt-get on the 2nd VM but I really couldn't tell what.
- The networking is also the same for both VMs.
- I can curl the repository URL just fine, so I don't think it's a firewall issue.

Here's also the output of `apt-get update` from the broken VM:

```
me@vm2-172-16-2-17:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable Release.gpg
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise Release.gpg
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security Release.gpg
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable Release
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable Release
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise Release
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security Release
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates Release
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable/main i386 Packages                     
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main TranslationIndex                  
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://my-mirror.com stable/main i386 Packages                     
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main TranslationIndex                  
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/universe amd64 Packages               
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages             
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages             
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/main i386 Packages                    
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/universe i386 Packages                
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages              
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise/restricted i386 Packages              
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/main TranslationIndex                 
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex           
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex           
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/universe TranslationIndex             
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com stable/main Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/main Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise/universe Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://my-mirror.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I setup the repository manually on VM1 by copying the `sources.list.d/foo.list` config from VM2, but I set it up using some puppet classes on VM2. I had forgotten that I setup [apt-pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto) using puppet, with `Pin-Priority: -10`
.

After deleting everything in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` and re-running `apt-get update && apt-get install apache2` things worked fine on VM2.